# C++ Subclassing, Inheritance and Casting

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, casting

This specific conundrum is hard for me to explain so I'll try as best I can.

In the Qt framework, there are 2 classes: QTreeWidget and QTreeWidgetitem.

I have subclassed a QTreeWidgetitem:

```
class MyQTreeWidgetitem : public QObject, public QTreeWidgetitem
{

...

public:
  int myCustomVariable;
}
```

I add this to a QTreeWidget doing something like:

```
MyQTreeWidgetitem *item = new MyQTreeWidgetitem;
item->myCustomVariable = 10;

tree->addTopLevelItem(item);
```

Now, if ever I need to call tree->topLevelItem(x), all I get back is the QTreeWidgetitem*.

However, what I'm after is the MyQTreeWidgetitem* so I:

```
MyQTreeWidgetItem *theitem = (MyQTreeWidgetItem*)tree->topLevelItem(n);
```

The problem with this is that theitem->myCustomVariable no longer equals 10.

Is there a way to keep MyQTreeWidgetitem intact?

Comment: Are you sure that `tree->topLevelItem(n);` is the original object you added?

Comment: Yes.. And templatetypedef's answer made me dig a little further. The dynamic_cast<> did work (!=0).. Upon further investigation with my class, the data (and everything else) does stay intact. I wish I could delete this question.

Comment: @ShiGon- The credit belongs to Tony, not me.  I just did a minor formatting cleanup on his answer to make it look shinier. :-)

Comment: You should still accept the answer since it did help you solve the problem.

Comment: Well, that's confusing.. Tony answered but templatetypedef edited?

Comment: @ShiGon, you can edit anyone's answers or questions when you reach 2000 reputation. You can even edit questions (not sure about answers) when you don't have that privilege, but then edits have to be accepted by several other people before they take effect. Also, you use @name (possibly shortened name) when replying to someone's comment, otherwise people won't get notified about your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Qq, but you could try doing a proper `dynamic_cast<>` which will verify whether the object is actually a `MyQTreeWidgetItem*` (otherwise returns 0), as well as performing the pointer conversion properly (I'm not sure if the C-style cast is returning the address of the `QObject`).  You can print out the pointers and get more insight into this problem too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After looking at the data inside of my subclass, I can see that the data is still there. The problem is not the casting after-all.

Answer (score 2):

Using a C-style cast in a C++ program is usually a bad idea. It may be okay to use it for primitive types, but should be avoided for classes. Although in this particular case it may be fine, one day you'll find yourself in deep trouble because of it.

Using `dynamic_cast<>` is probably fine. As you don't use virtual inheritance, you may wish to use `static_cast<>` too, it has advantage of not requiring RTTI (some platforms may have poor support of it) and being slightly faster. I also heard that dynamic_cast sometimes doesn't work properly across shared library boundaries.

For downcasting between QObject subclasses there is also `qobject_cast<>` available in Qt. It won't help you in this case as QTreeWidgetItem isn't a QObject subclass, but may help you elsewhere where you need to cast from QObject* to MyQTreeWidgetItem*. It is also used to cast to interfaces if you use Qt plugins mechanism.